# mFOLD prediction result interpretation

Tags: bioinformatics, structure-prediction, microrna

I am trying to predict the secondary structure of certain predicted pre-miRNAs through mFOLD which is the generally accepted technique for structure prediction in most studies. I am finding it hard to interpret the result and accept if the pre-miRNA which I have picked and the miRNA I have can be accepted and included in my result.

This is one predicted pre-miRNA structure with the predicted miRNA position shown in green. 
[image]

**Is this a good/bad structure and if so, can anyone give me a reason why. Thank you.**

edit: I understand that energy levels are also something that is looked for in the prediction. In this particular figure, ΔG = -75.00 kcal/mol which I think is fine.

Sequence used for folding is

```
AAAAATAAAAAACAGAACCATGAGGCAGCGCACCAAGAGCGTCGTGAACGTCCGCGAATA CTTCCGCATGGACGGCAGTGGCGCCCCCGAGCAGGAGGACGACGATGACAACGATGACTG GATGGCCATCGCCATGCAGGGCGCACCGCGTAAGGTCAGCGTGGAAGTCGTTAAGCCTGG CAAGAAGGCACGCGCTCGTACGTCGACGTGTGACTCAC
```

and the highlighted match area is

```
ACGATGACAACGATGAC
```

So this structure should be fine because the sequence lies along a stem-loop structure.
[image]

I am worried about that bulge on the left top corner though. That doesn't affect the predictability of this structure does it?

Comment: As a non-specialist reader, I wonder when you say mMFOLD is a "technique" if you mean it's software?

Comment: @daniel yup software

Comment: Can I know more about the settings of this prediction? Temperature, ionic strenght, molarity etc? You could post the link to the job results on the mfold server so I can better evaluate the likelihood of this structure.

Comment: @alec_djinn I have moved past this project but I generally stick to default parameters for prediction. The paper titled "Bioinformatic discovery of microRNA precursors from human ESTs and introns" gave me a guideline for identifying a viable precursor which I follow currently. But it would of course be helpful to know how the prediction is done. I will make sure to contact you the next time I do a precursor prediction and give you a link. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The green region will definitely not make an miRNA: It is not a part of a stem loop. See typical miRNA structures from miRbase.

**EDIT**

Bulges can sometimes determine which strand is chosen as mature miRNA. However, this green region is also is unlikely to form miRNA because the stem is just 15bp.

Comment: Please look at the edit of the question.

Comment: I didn't know if I should ask this as a separate question so, I am posting it as a comment. In one paper (http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/21/18/3610.abstract, I found that ~70 nt of the matched flanking area was taken as pre-miRNA while in this paper (http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijg/2012/957607/) ~100 flanking nt of the match area was taken for pre-miRNA structure prediction. Any idea why so?

Comment: no idea.. it is best to take 60-70 nt from either side (because you don't yet know that your read is -3p or -5p). I suggest that you use a machine learning algorithm to predict the right miRNA structure. Co-incidentally a friend of mine was working on similar problem and was talking to me about it (for a moment I thought you and her are same people :P ). I'll let you know if we make some progress.

Comment: I'll post it as a question then to see if anybody else could get some light on the issue..